# Fullscreen to different components in flash

Tags: flash, fullscreen

I'm developing a website in flash which have the option to be displayed in fullscreen, but the website has a video player inside which has the same functionality. When I change the web to fullscreen mode the video is displayed instead of the main web. I have figured out that the instruction is also the same, so how can I decide which component should be displayed in fullscreen? The video or the main web depending on the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you mean by "video player".

If it is a FLVPlayback component that you incorporate in your application, then you can set the [fullScreenTakeOver](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#fullScreenTakeOver) property.

If it is a third-party player, like for example the JW Player or the players from YouTube or Vimeo, you would have to look in to what they support, individually.